# Cannot build Store Package - error

Tags: compiler-errors, visual-studio-2015

```
Unable to remove directory "obj\x86\Release\PackageUploadLayout\". The process cannot access the file 'System.Collections.Immutable.dll' because it is being used by another process.
```

I cannot build my Store package! I restarted VS , I restarted the system , I cleaned the solution , no result same issue.The app builds , works fine , I just cannot create the Store package and I am trying to update an app that I already have submitted. Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have the same issue. Were you able to solve it?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This worked for me. Go to the project folder and delete the "obj" folder. It might complain about "System.Collections.Immutable.dll", Just close Visual studio and continue the deletion.

Comment: Interesting , I will give it a try. I don't really know what's the problem but , each time it gives me a compilation error , I restart VS and close any project file that is opened. I don't know man. Really buggy VS 2015.

Comment: Tried it , I think this fixed the problem.

Comment: Exactly what is described in the question started happening for me all of a sudden without any specific rhyme or reason. I closed VS 2015, removed the obj folder, reopened VS 2015. Then, I was able to build my package for the Store again.

Answer (score 1):

Deleting the obj folder, shutting down VS and rebooting did not solve the problem for me.  I had to create a new project to finally resolve the problem.

Comment: I wanted to downvote this just because it made me sad :(